# Saving multiple Markers through SharedPreferences

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, sharedpreferences

I have found some tuts on how to do add multiple markers on your map fragment. But in my case, It seems that it doesn't work for me, well I can put multiple markers but whenever I restart the application those markers that was save through sharedpreferences is gone.

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("location", 0);

    locationCount = prefs.getInt("locationCount", 0);

    if(locationCount != 0){
        String lat = "";
        String lng = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < locationCount; i++) {
            lat = prefs.getString("Lat" + i,"0");
            lng = prefs.getString("Lng" + i, "0");
            drawMaker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)));
        }
    }

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
            locationCount++;

            drawMaker(latLng);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            editor.putString("lat" + Integer.toString((locationCount - 1)), Double.toString(latLng.latitude));

            editor.putString("lng" + Integer.toString((locationCount - 1)), Double.toString(latLng.longitude));

            editor.putInt("locationCount", locationCount);

            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Marker is added to the Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
            mMap.clear();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            editor.clear();

            editor.commit();

            locationCount = 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try to save a list of objects to shared preferences. In your case it is a List<Location>. When your maps activity starts get the list and put marker in a for loop. [try this](https://mobikul.com/storing-list-in-shared-preference-android/)

Comment: I don't quite get how list works but imma give it a try. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I think I have found the solution to it. It's just that the key value on passing the SharedPreference to the editor is wrong instead of `lat` and `lng` it should be `Lat` and `Lng` I just forgot that its case sensitive